# How to use WriteElementString?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I'm new in processing XML document with C#.

My C# code:

```
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlElement childNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("link:schemaRef");
root.AppendChild(childNode);

XmlAttribute type = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xlink:type");
type.Value = "simple";
childNode.Attributes.Append(type);

XmlAttribute type2 = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xlink:href");
type2.Value = "http://taxonomi.xbrl.se/se/fr/sme/rbf/2008-09-30/se-sme-rbf-2008-09-30.xsd";
childNode.Attributes.Append(type2);
```

but with that code will produce XML like this:

```
<schemaRef type="simple" href="http://taxonomi.xbrl.se/se/fr/sme/rbf/2008-09-30/se-sme-rbf-2008-09-30.xsd" />
```

However, XML element that I want to produce look like this:

```
<link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://taxonomi.xbrl.se/se/fr/sme/rbf/2008-09-30/se-sme-rbf-2008-09-30.xsd" />
```

---

I think I've got the solution for my question, below is my C# code, working as my temporary solution:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"" + dir + "" + filename);

XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

//##Insert XBRL link scheme
var schemaRefElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("link", "schemaRef", "urn:linkbase");
schemaRefElement.SetAttribute("type", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "simple");
schemaRefElement.SetAttribute("href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink","http://www.bi.go.id/xbrl/2012-06 18/view/Pelaporan%20Keuangan/Rincian%20aset%20non%20finansial/" + reportname + "/" + reportname + ".xsd");
root.AppendChild(schemaRefElement);
xmlDoc.Save(@"" + dir + "" + filename);
```

but I'm still look for other best solution; actually I prefer to use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

this example may helping you

```
XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
XElement xmlTree = new XElement(aw + "Root",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "aw", "http://www.adventure-works.com"),
    new XAttribute(aw + "Att", "attribute content")
);
XAttribute att = xmlTree.Attribute(aw + "Att");
Console.WriteLine(att);
```

Output:

> aw:Att="attribute content"

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var mmd = doc.CreateElement("mmd");
var element = doc.CreateElement("link", "schemaRef", "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase");
            mmd.AppendChild(element);

XmlAttribute xmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("xlink", "type", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
xmlAttribute.Value = "simple";
element.Attributes.Append(xmlAttribute);

xmlAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute("xlink", "href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
xmlAttribute.Value = "http://taxonomi.xbrl.se/se/fr/sme/rbf/2008-09-30/se-sme-rbf-2008-09-30.xsd";
element.Attributes.Append(xmlAttribute);
```